# Django, calendar widget doesn't work with ModelForm and Form Media

Tags: javascript, python, css, django, forms

I found one [blog](http://pyred.net/coding/2016/10/13/writing-javascript-for-django-widgets). It explains how apply calendar widget with form media. It is what I exactly want to make. so I followed instructions.

But js and css files doesn't work in widget. I tried to figure out this problem. I spent quite much time by searching and reading stuffs. But I can't get what's wrong in my situation exactly. Well, It could be very easy question but I will appreciate if you can give me any hint to figure out this!

model.py

```
class Birthday(models.Model):
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True)
```

views.py

```
def register_birthday(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BirthdayForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success')
    else:
        form = BirthdayForm()
    return render(request, 'sale/registerbirthday.html', {'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class DateUIWidget(forms.TextInput):
    def _media(self):
        return forms.Media(css = {
            "all": ("tiny-date-picker.css",)
        },
        js = ("tiny-date-picker.js", "date-init.js",))
    media = property(_media)


class BirthdayForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Birthday
        fields = ('birthday',)
        widgets = {
            "birthday" : DateUIWidget(attrs={'class':'dateuiwidget', 'id':'id_birthday'}),
        }
```

actually I wrote at first like below. but I changed to check if it works when I use media as a dynamic property.

```
class DateUIWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ("tiny-date-picker.css",)
        }
        js = ("tiny-date-picker.js", "date-init.js",)
```

forms.py first

```
<form action="." method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit">
</form>
{{ form.medai}}
```

I changed it because I read that I should read this when I changed. 
[As we have already seen, the string representation of a Media object is the HTML required to include the relevant files in the `<head>` block of your HTML page.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/media/#media-objects)

```
<html>

<head>
{{ form.media }}
</head>

<body>
<form action="." method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

under myapp/static/date-init.js

```
$(".dateuiwidget").each(function(){
    return TinyDatePicker(this);
});
```

I copied two files(tiny-date-picker.js,tiny-date-picker.css) under myapp/static/.
I got two files from [here](https://github.com/chrisdavies/tiny-date-picker)

it shows widget in a form without error. I assume that somehow js, css file didn't apply to this widget.

```
html source code
<html>

<head>
<link href="/static/tiny-date-picker.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/tiny-date-picker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/date-init.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="." method="post">
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='VC8ahwDLBOsy4IlAzf1iIiukK7ZvTcGDQjL9RxywlauCOX3c8rG7DVJ1ClozHEEW' />
<p><label for="id_birthday">Birthday:</label> <input class="dateuiwidget" id="id_birthday" name="birthday" type="text" required /></p>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "I changed it because I read that I should read this when I changed" mean?